# Is it possible to write a Chrome App without Angular.js?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm looking for (and not finding) tutorials on how to build a Chrome native app (meaning, something that can be launched via its own icon from the Desktop) without Angular.js.  Are the two technologies now totally married? Or is it possible to write a Web App in good old HTML5 without all the overhead (and in my opinion awfulness) of Angular? And if it is possible, where does one begin?

Comment: Ah... good ole' -1 with no explanation. Thanks! Very helpful.

Comment: (I'm not the one who voted you down.) A Chrome App is not a Web App. Chrome Apps can have their own icon, and launch even if Chrome isn't running. (In that case Chrome gets launched in the background.) I'm surprised at your question, because in my experience about 99% of the documentation on writing Chrome Apps is about using plain JavaScript, and only 1% is about using Angular. If you google "Develop Chrome App" you'll get the principal Google documentation right away, and very little of it is about Angular. Or, read my book. (You can google for that, too.)

Comment: @MarcRochkind, Bernie's Bar & Girll? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, that's me. Did you read it?

But a more relevant book is Programming Chrome Apps, to be published in a month or so by O'Reilly, and now available as an Early Release.

Comment: Thanks! I will definitely pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing forcing you to write a Chrome app with anything more than the standard tools: HTML5, CSS and Javascript. Libraries such as Angular may be helpful. For example, the Chrome Dev Editor, currently available as a developer preview, is written in Dart (compiled to Javascript) using the Polymer framework. The code is available here:

https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor

A number of example apps are included with the editor.

The Chrome App Samples repository contains dozens of example apps showing off various APIs. None of the ones I've written use Angular:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples